Adding a Button with cookie durations
To frame what im trying to do. I work for a small reatailer and we had an idea for a promotion where we put a gift card in a small safe. The Safe has the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and needs 5 a digit code to open. Im building a page on our website for customers to generater their code. I want to add a limit to how many times somebody can click the button to gerneate A code. Right now it will just endlessly generate codes if you spam the button... What am i doing wrong?
Script
<script>
function randomString() {
      
    var characters = "12345";
    var ClickCount = 0;
    function countClicks() {
        var clickLimit = 1; //Max number of clicks
        if (ClickCount >= clickLimit) {
            
            alert("You can only click this button " + 1 + " time.");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            ClickCount++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // CHECK COOKIE
    setTimeout(function () {
        
    }, 1000);
      
    var lenString = 5;
    var randomstring = '';

      
    for (var i = 0; i < lenString; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
        randomstring += characters.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }

    //display the generated string   
    document.getElementById("randomfield").innerHTML = randomstring;
}  
</script>

HTML
<h2 style="color: green"> Random Safe Code </h2>  
<h3> Click the button to generate your code </h3>  
  
<form name="randomform">  
   <input type="button" value="Generate Code" onClick="randomString();">  
   <br><br>  
   <b><p id="randomfield" style="color: green"> </p></b>  
</form>

Ideally I'd like for the cookie to reset every 7 Days.

Doesn't answer your question, but be careful storing this as a cookie. The user can clear their cookies at any point to allow for regenerating as many codes as they want. It may be better to do this on the server side some way. You could grab the users IP address and only allow an IP to generate a code every so often. But storing this restriction as a cookie will not prevent the same user from getting more codes if they simply switch browsers, clear their cache, etc.

That code looks a lot more like JavaScript than Java, both completely different languages. Are you sure that you tagged your question correctly? No sense getting the folk who might not know a lot of JS attracted to your question.

You never call countClicks()

FYI characters.substring(rnum, rnum + 1) can be simplified to just characters[rnum]

You shouldn't initialize the click counter inside the function that runs when you click the button. It needs to be initialized before the click, then incremented inside the function.

What's supposed to happen inside the setTimeout() function?

This probably should all be done on the server, not the client. If it's on the server, the user can easily use DevTools to get the random code.

Yeah, that wa a typo, I meant on the client.

did you notice your form is being submitted when you click the button inside it?
